# return response data from async call

Tags: node.js, axios, google-drive-api

I created this function to get list all my drives from GDrive.

```js
    async getAllDrives(token) {
        let nextPageToken = ""
        let resultArray = []        
        const config= {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        };
        const bodyParams = {            
            pageSize: 2,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, drives(id, name)',
            q:`hidden=false`,
        };
        do {
            axios.get(
                `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives`,
                config,
                bodyParams,
            ).then(result => {
                nextPageToken = result.data.nextPageToken;  
                resultArray.push(result.data.drives);
                resultArray = resultArray.flat();                
                console.log("result", resultArray);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                //res.send(error);
            });
        }while(nextPageToken);
        resultArray = resultArray.flat();
        resultArray.map(drive => {
            drive.isSharedDrive = true;
        return drive;
        });
        return JSON.stringify(resultArray);
        
    }
```

When I look in console.log

```js
then(result => {
                nextPageToken = result.data.nextPageToken;  
                resultArray.push(result.data.drives);
                resultArray = resultArray.flat();                
                console.log("result", resultArray);

            })
```

I have the expected result,

```js
result [
  {
    kind: 'drive#drive',
    id: '**',
    name: ' ★ '
  },
]
```

but `return JSON.stringify(resultArray);` is empty.
I found a similar question here, [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but the answer is not satisfying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the drive list using axios.
- Your access token can be used for retrieving the drive list using Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- In order to use `nextPageToken` in the request, in this case, it is required to run the script with a synchronous process. So, async/await is used. This has already been mentioned in the existing answers.
- When I saw your script, I thought that the query parameter might be required to be included in the 2nd argument of `axios.get()`.
- In order to use `nextPageToken`, it is required to include the property of `pageToken`. In your script, `pageToken` is not used. By this, the infinite loop occurs because `nextPageToken` is continued to be returned.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
let resultArray = [];
const config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  params: {
    pageSize: 2,
    fields: "nextPageToken, drives(id, name)",
    q: `hidden=false`,
    pageToken: "",
  },
};
do {
  const { data } = await axios
    .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives`, config)
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.data);
      }
    });
  if (data.drives.length > 0) {
    resultArray = [...resultArray, ...data.drives];
  }
  nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
  config.params.pageToken = nextPageToken;
} while (nextPageToken);
resultArray.map((drive) => {
  drive.isSharedDrive = true;
  return drive;
});
return JSON.stringify(resultArray);
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  {"id":"###","name":"###","isSharedDrive":true},
  {"id":"###","name":"###","isSharedDrive":true},
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

#### Note:

- From the official document of "Drives: list",

  > `pageSize`: Maximum number of shared drives to return per page. Acceptable values are 1 to 100, inclusive. (Default: 10)

  - So, when `pageSize` is 100, the number of loops can be reduced. If you want to test the loop using `nextPageToken`, please reduce the value.

#### References:

- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list)

Answer (score 1):

You used the async call slightly incorrectly. You calling `axios.get` without `await` keyword, but with `.then` chaining. Since you don't wait for result to return, you getting empty array first, returning you nothing. And **only then** your callback function inside `.then` is getting called. To simplify, you doing this in your example:

```js
function getAllDrives() {
    // Local variable where you want your result
    let result = [];
    
    // You calling the axios.get method, but don't wait for result
    axios.get().then(result => {})
    
    // Empty result is getting returned immediately
    return result;
}
```

And when response is returned from the remote server, function inside `.then` trying to save result to local variable. But function is already completed, so you don't get anything.

What you actually should do is call `axios.get` with `await` keyword:

```js
// You should always cover your asynchronous code with a try/catch block
try {
    
    // Instead of `then` callback use `await` keyword. Promise returned from
    // this method will contain result. If error occurs, it will be thrown,
    // and you can catch it inside `catch`.
    const result = await axios.get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives`,
        config,
        bodyParams
    );

    // Here is your code as you wrote it inside `then` callback
    nextPageToken = result.data.nextPageToken;
    resultArray.push(result.data.drives);
    resultArray = resultArray.flat();
    console.log("result", resultArray);
    
} catch (error) {
    
    // And here is your error handling code as you wrote it inside `catch`
    console.log(error);
    
}
```

This way your method will not complete until your request is not executed.

You can read more about async/await functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: in fact i do exactly the same thing but idk  nextPageToken is never empty (infinity loop)

 ```
nextPageToken = await result.data.nextPageToken;
 if(nextPageToken)
           bodyParams.pageToken = nextPageToken;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you study a little more about async/await.
It makes no sense for you to use async and put a `.then().catch()`, the purpose of async to get these encapsulated syntaxes.

```js
async getAllDrives(token) {
  try {
    const getDrives = await this.request(token)
    console.log(getDrives)

    const results = this.resultArray(getDrives)
    return results
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

I didn't quite understand your while or your objective, adapt it to your code or remove it

```js
async request(token) {
  let nextPageToken = 1 // ????????
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  };
  const bodyParams = {            
    pageSize: 2,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, drives(id, name)',
    q: `hidden=false`,
  };
        
  let getDrives = [];
  // loop for each request and create a request array
  for (let x = 0; x < fields.nextPageToken; x++) { 
    const request = axios.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives`,
      config,
      bodyParams
    );
        
    getDrives.push(request)
  }
        
  const drives = await Promise.all(getDrives)
  return drives
}

async resultArray(drivers) {
  // result treatment here
}
```

The return of promise all will be an array of the driver's responses

Note: The response in request.data

```js
const request = await axios.get()
const resposta = request.data
```

Read about
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all